# Recursion without calling previous functions

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, recursion, uicollectionview

How one can create a recursion function that once called will only execute the current called function that has the next index?

The collection view to be auto scrolled is nested inside the first table view cell.

I've been trying to create a recursion function that would work as a regular loop. The loops can not be used because it runs on a background thread.

This is my code:

```
var indexItem = 1

func autoScroll(time: Int) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.run(after: time) {
            cell._collectionView.scrollToItem(
                at: IndexPath(row: indexItem, section: 0),
                at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true
            )
            indexItem += 1
            autoScroll(time: 3)
            return
        }
    }
}

autoScroll(time: 3)
```

The problem is that it always calls the function with the previous index first, then it executes the function with the actual index.

Comment: What do you mean it "always calls the previous function"?

Comment: It executes firstly scrollToItem() with the previous index, so it scrolls back, then comes to the current item and after all of this scrolls further to the next item in list.

Comment: What I need is a recursion function that would work as a regular loop. The loops can  not be used because it runs on a background thread.

Comment: Maybe you can step back and describe the actual problem you’re trying solve, rather than us trying to diagnose this particular attempt at a solution. This notion of “recursion that only happens once” seems curious, so I’d let go of that for a sec and focus on the broader problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `autoScroll(time: 3*indexItem)` at both the function calling places can work?;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is this:

```
func autoScroll(time: DispatchTimeInterval, indexItem: Int = 1) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + time) {
        cell._collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: indexItem, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        autoScroll(time: time, indexItem: indexItem + 1)
    }
}

autoScroll(time: .seconds(3))
```

Just pass the value to the function.

You really need some flag that will stop this, though. As written, this is ensuring that `cell` can never be released. And if multiple cells run this, then it's definitely going to cause a problem a they fight. I would expect this to run directly on the collection view rather than on the cell.